# Where's the MediaCodecInfo comes from?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediacodec, android-profiler

I'm using AndroidStudio profiler to view the app heap. And I saw many HashMap with `MediaCodecInfo`, like the below picture:
[image]

[image]

I global search `MediaCodecInfo` in my project, there's no results.

I checked Android document
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec

> MediaCodec class can be used to access low-level media codecs, i.e.
> encoder/decoder components. It is part of the Android low-level
> multimedia support infrastructure (normally used together with
> MediaExtractor, MediaSync, MediaMuxer, MediaCrypto, MediaDrm, Image,
> Surface, and AudioTrack.)

I just used SoundPool in my project which should nothing to do with this.

Any way to find out what's it used for in my project? Not sure if it's something relative to system and should leave it there.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I removed `SoundPool` and still get this.

Answer (score 0):

Here the quote from `SoundPool` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool):

> The SoundPool library uses the MediaCodec service to decode the audio
> into raw 16-bit PCM. This allows applications to ship with compressed
> streams without having to suffer the CPU load and latency of
> decompressing during playback.

So as you can see `SoundPool` uses `MediaCodec` api under the hood, so that's why you see `MediaCodecInfo` objects in the heap.

Also maybe there is some library that your project depends on and it uses `MediaCodec` api too.

Comment: I removed `SoundPool` and still get them. I guess might be in some libraries, hard to check it.

Comment: maybe you're also using MediaPlayer or some other stuff relative to MediaCodec?